# MVVM Light installer for latest version

Tags: mvvm-light

I'd like to use the latest version of MVVM Light (NuGet has version 4.2.30) with the VS templates. The official installer has version 4.1. I'm using VS 2013.

Any help on how to get the latest version with all templates and snippets etc. is highly appreciated.

Cheers,

Jan

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any installer for mvvmlight that adds the project types to Visual Studio 2013.

The latest official version is 4.2.30 : https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight

To install the latest version of MVVM Light, use the console command and type :

```
Install-Package MvvmLight
```

[image: mvvm-light]

Comment: What do you mean by project types ? the dlls !

Comment: Nuget provides the DLLs, but not the templates. To get those, run the vsix file from CodePlex: http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/115541

Answer (score 0):

There is not an official download version for nuget version 4.2.30. To get the templates ready to use you can download the 4.1 toolkit (http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/releases) and then manually copy the projectTemplates and the itemTemplates to Visual Studio folder Templates:
Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates

Hope it helps